# Error: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty - Django webdev

Tags: python, django, settings

I developed a simpel web application in django and everything is working perfectly. I did push the code already to Heroku and no errors appeared. Now i'm trying to set my secret key and other vital settings to environment variables. I'm on a Windows and set everything correctly in the control panel. when i test the secret key with:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY_THIJS')
print(SECRET_KEY)
```

It prints out the secret key correctly. When i try to push the code to Heroku via Git is says: 
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Please help me out!

*Note: excuse me for me English and i am a hobby programmer and did not have any education related to it (learned everything via Google and Youtube) :)

Sincerely,

Rick

Comment: Well did you set the `SECRET_KEY_THIJS` in your Horeku environment?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: i did set the secrey key in the heroku environment with the actual secret key, not the environment variable. Do i need to set it like: SECREY_KEY_THIJS = 'Actual secret key'?

Comment: It should look like this: `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` (on the left) and `<SECRET_KEY`> on the right. Is that what you did?

Comment: i did set the variable in Heroku like: DJANGO_SECRET_KEY (left) = SECRET_KEY (variable in source code on the right). Or do i need to specify the actual secret key within the heroku environment?